# Modal do bootstrap não abre

Tags: bootstrap-3, modal

Tenho um botão que ao ser clicado abre uma modal do bootstrap. Porém ao clicar nesse botão, a modal não está abrindo. Segue a estrutura do código:

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <script src="assets/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">Open Modal</button>

        <div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

A versão do bootstrap que importei no meu projeto é a última. O que pode ser

Comment: O que é apresentado no console (F12)? Você precisa inserir o javascript do JQuery e do Bootstrap no final da página!

Comment: Não aparece nada. E não dá nenhum erro no load da página também

Comment: Está com o `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">` no final da página, assim como o JQuery? Se estiver usando somente o `.css` como está aí, não irá funcionar.

Comment: Adicionei o <script src="assets/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> que estava faltando e também não foi. Nao adicionei eles no final da página. Eu adicionei eles no <head>

Comment: @RaphaelPradodeOliveira tem ordem para adicionar, primeiro o jquery, depois o bootstrap.js. **Basta** seguir a documentação http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você não fez os `imports` corretamente.

```html
<html>
    <head>   
      <!-- Importando o css do bootstrap -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">Diga olá para o mundo!</button>

        <div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal de Olá!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Estou dizendo! OLÁ MUNDO! =D</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

    </body>

  <!-- Importando o jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Importando o js do bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```